How can I evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{(x - \frac{1}{2}})}\, \mathrm{d}x$?
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{(x - \frac{1}{2}})}\, \mathrm{d}x$$ I have tried using the substitution $x - \frac{1}{2} = t$ and the integral that resulted was:
$$\int_\frac{-1}{2}^\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin{(x + \frac{1}{2})}}{\cos{x}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$ which is very similar to the first integral. Working the term with $\sin$ using trigonometry got me to $$2\sin{\frac{x + \frac{1}{2}}{2}}\cos{\frac{x - \frac{1}{2}}{2}}$$ which doesn't really simplify the integral. Is there another way to do a substituion such that the integral can be solved more easily?

So, we can write
$$\newcommand{\II}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\mathcal{I} := \int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{\cos ( x - \frac 1 2 )} \, \dd x
= \int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{\cos \frac 1 2 \cos x + \sin \frac 1 2 \sin x} \, \dd x
$$
by an angle difference formula. This is, essentially, just a rational function of sine and cosine. This means the integral admits the Weierstrass substitution
$$
t = \tan \frac x 2
\qquad
\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}
\qquad
\cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
\qquad
\dd x = \frac{2 \, \dd t}{1+t^2}
$$
from which you can get a solution by using partial fraction decomposition.

$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{\cos \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)} d x 
= & \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\sin \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\cos x} d x, \text { where } x \mapsto x-\frac{1}{2} \\
= & \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\sin x \cos \frac{1}{2}+\sin \frac{1}{2} \cos x}{\cos x} d x \\
= & 0+\sin \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} 1 d x \quad (\textrm{ as }\tan x \textrm{  is odd}) \\
= & \sin \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

I also found a more sophisticated (but nice) answer to this question: it involves trying to write $\cos(x - \frac{1}{2})$ as a sum of sin's. Let $I$ be the integral.
$$
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{\left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)}} \, \text{d}x = 2\sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} \cdot \int_0^1 \frac{\sin{x}}{2\sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} \cos{\left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)}} \, \text{d}x
$$
The idea is to write that product as a sum:
$$
2\sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} \cos{\left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)} = 2\sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} \cos{\left( \frac{2x - 1}{2} \right)} = 
\sin{x} + \sin{(1 - x)}
$$
$$
I = 2\sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} \cdot \int_0^1 \frac{\sin{x}}{\sin{x} + \sin{(1 - x)}} \, \text{d}x
$$
Now solve this integral by the substitution $x = 1 - t, \text{d}x = -\text{d}t$:
$$
I = 2\sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} \cdot \int_0^1 \frac{\sin{(1 - t)}}{\sin{(1 - t)} + \sin{t}} \, \text{d}t
$$
$$
I = 2\sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} \cdot \int_0^1 \frac{\sin{(1 - t)} + \sin{t} - \sin{t}}{\sin{(1 - t)} + \sin{t}} \, \text{d}t = 2\sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} \cdot  \int_0^1 \text{d}t - I
$$
This simplifies to:
$$
I = \sin{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)}
$$
Thank you for all the answers!
